# Problema de navegación en Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic, angular-router

muestro antes de nada el layout que estoy usando en mi aplicación Ionic 4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en cualquiera de las opciones del Sidebar éste carga la cabecera en Manage Header y a su vez, este último, carga un listado en Content. Mi problema es, que esa página que carga en Content tiene un botón que debería cargar otra página en Content nuevamente y no consigo que la ruta sea reconocida.

Expongo el código:

**app.component.html**

```
    <ion-app>
        <ion-split-pane>
            <ion-menu contentId="rightPane">
........ * Opciones del menú * -------
            </ion-menu>
            <ion-router-outlet id="rightPane" main></ion-router-outlet>
        </ion-split-pane>
    </ion-app>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule' },
    { path: 'manage', loadChildren: './pages/manage/manage.module#ManagePageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**manage.page.html**

```
<app-header-manage></app-header-manage>

<ion-content>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

**manage.page.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'companies/list', <- funciona correctamente
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'companies',
    component: ManagePage,
    children: [
        { path: 'list', loadChildren: '../companies/list/list.module#ListPageModule' },
        { path: 'add', loadChildren: '../companies/add/add.module#AddPageModule' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ManagePage, HeaderManageComponent]
})
export class ManagePageModule {}
```

**list.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <app-search [placeholder]="'Buscar cliente'" (changeText)="newSearch($event)"></app-search>
        <ion-button slot="end" size="default" color="success" (click)="goCompaniesAdd()"> <- Click para navegar a la siguiente página
......
......
```

**list.page.ts**

```
....
  goCompaniesAdd() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('add'); <- ERROR: No se puede encontrar la ruta
  }
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en la ruta que se estaba indicando.

Lo correcto sería en **list.page.ts** poner:

```
  goCompaniesAdd() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('*/manage/companies/add*');
  }
```